# Ordering an array from another c++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11

I'm trying to order an array with another but I don't know how to do, I know `std::sort` exist but I don't know how to use it with another array.

**Explications:**

I've got a structure with multiple vectors:

```
struct Data
{
   std::vector<float> zPosition;
   std::vector<float> alpha;
   std::vector<int>   life;
   std::vector<Color> colors; // rgba (unsigned char)
   …
}
```

I would like to sort zPosition array (far to nearest) but **I can't swap every arrays for performance reasons**.

So my idea is to use another array `std::vector<int> IDArray`. The objective is to sort this array with `zPosition` data (and later the goal would be to put element with `life = 0` at the end of the array)

During rendering, I could do something like that:

```
for( int i = 0; i < Data.elementCount; i++ )
{
   int ID = IDArray[i];

   float zPosition = Data.zPosition[ID];
   float alpha     = Data.alpha[ID];
   // ...
}
```

I would like to use std::sort but this method will sort `zPosition` array, not ID array.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: @awesomeyi They want to sort all of the vectors by the elements of only one of the vectors. However, they don't actually want to move the elements of all the vectors around. Instead, they want a list of indices in sorted order.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a container `IDArray` with all the `int` indices in it, you can then do:

```
std::sort(IDArray.begin(), IDArray.end(), [&data](int index1, int index2) {
  return data.zPosition[index1] < data.zPosition[index2];
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about capture variable ([&]) :)